# Reload UITableView with a different number of rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've got a UITableView set up and working, and now I have a little issue. I need to reload the tableView's data whenever the view loads, and one thing which I can't get working is attempting to reload the data, when there was no data in the table view to begin with.

Basically the list is of variable length, and the contents are loaded from a file, what I want to know is, is there I way I can force the table to reload and not have it ignore the datasource methods, as is what happens whenever [tableView reloadData] is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[tableView reloadData]` relies entirely on the data source methods! So, the only way you would see your data source methods beind ignored would be that you have not set the data source (and perhaps delegate) of your table view to be the object you want to be the data source. You can set these through Interface Builder, or programatically, e.g.:

```
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Both the datasource/delegate are set, but I get the feeling that it only reloads data for each cell already in the table, in this case 0.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. A typical implementation for `numberOfRowsInSection:` is to return the count of objects in an array. So I have to believe that a data source method like that is consulted often. You could set a breakpoint in that method to verify if it is being called. Of course, you have to actually call `reloadData:`. I assume you're at least doing that, right? :-)

Comment: Right, I set the breakpoint, and found that it is called every time the view loads, and double checked I was calling reloadData :) And now it appears to be working. This must have been to do with another view writing to a file and messing it up - yay for misc errors! But at least we know that the numberOfRowsInSection is called every time now.

Comment: Nice. I love it when odd behavior just "goes away" but the Professional Software Developer in me always is unnerved by not knowing exactly what was going on in the first place... :-)

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling, but I'm not worried, I'm sure it'll come back around and get me one day soon...

Answer (score 1):

> whenever the view loads

Where do you call *reloadData*? Do you call it in *-viewDidLoad* method? If yes it is probably incorrect, because *-viewDidLoad* is called only once - when view of the corresponding UIViewController is created (on the first usage). Maybe you should take a look at *-viewWillAppear* which is called(assuming correct usage of UIViewController) whenever view is going to be displayed.

The other possible reason is that if you do use *-viewWillAppear* (or *-viewDidAppear*) it is not triggered at all. This can happen if you use a custom UIViewController hierarchy. In that case you must call it with your own hands (there are exceptions - UINavigationController for example does this for you, but simple *[someView addSubview:myController.view]* doesn't).

Also please check if delegates are set correctly and tableView is not equal to nil (as you know messages to nil are just ignored).

Comment: Yep, using -viewDidAppear, I've checked this method, and it is being called every time the view is loaded (tableview controller within a tabbar controller). And the delegates are indeed set up. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

datasource methods aren't ignored when u call [tableView reloadData];
Did u set the IBOUTLET and the sources right?